# How do I automatically tail (delete) older logs using Serilog in a .Net WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serilog

I'm using Serliog in a .Net WPF application.

Is there a way that I can "tail" (delete) the log files automatically when they are over N days old?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/blob/dev/README.md
Look there. You can configure autocreation of a new log file every day and also you can set how many of them you want to be kept

Comment: So essentially the answer is NO, according to that.

Comment: Well you can configure rolling file for once a day and then set `retainedFileCountLimit` to desired days limit...

Comment: @WoIIe it is indeed not a direct answer to the question but it solves the problem of deleting old logs

Comment: This answer a) relies on an external link rather than copying relevant information, and b) is somewhat outdated as the "rollingfile" sink has been merged into the regular "file" sync. I recommend looking at the next answer.

Comment: yup serilog have default implementation for deleting older log files. if we set the rollingInterval to day, it will only keep the last 31 days logs(which is configurable).

Answer (score 32):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/README.md#limits), the retention period for logs is determined by the `retainedFileCountLimit` setting. By default, `retainedFileCountLimit` has a value of 31 so only the most recent 31 log files are kept.

When configuring `Serilog` programmatically, you can adjust the number of files retained by specifying the `retainedFileCountLimit` parameter as follows:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", retainedFileCountLimit: 42)
    .CreateLogger();
```

pass `null` to remove the limit.

When configuring `Serilog` using XML (in the `<appSettings>`):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="log.txt" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.retainedFileCountLimit" value="42"/>
</appSettings>
```

and pass an empty string to remove the limit.

When configuring `Serilog` using JSON (in an `appsettings.json` file):

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log.txt",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": "42"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and pass an empty string to remove the limit.

Answer (score 7):

Now you can also specify a property `retainedFileTimeLimit`:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/pull/90

By the way, don't forget to specify `retainedFileCountLimit: null` if you want limitation only by the date. With the current implementation default value of retainedFileCountLimit is 31. Therefore, if you leave the parameter out, this filter will also be applied